# Recommendation for maven plugin to automatically bump the project.version based on conventional commits

Tags: maven, conventional-commits

When working with nx monorepos I can make use of a plugin (https://github.com/jscutlery/semver) that automatically bumps the package.json versions using semver 2.0.0 based on the commit messages made.

Is there something similar for maven?

Comment: Something like this: https://revapi.org/revapi-site/main/getting-started.html

Comment: Does it analyze the commit messages? Couldn't find the keyword "commit" in the docs ;)

Comment: Why should it check the commit message? The important part is if the code introduces breaking change or not... etc.

Comment: true. didn't have that in mind as was focused on getting the commit messages nice and more helpful recently ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes that exists.
Have a look at this custom VersionPolicy (= next version calculator) for the maven-release-plugin that does this using the Conventional Commits model.

https://github.com/nielsbasjes/conventional-commits-maven-release